# Why same user has different password and system properties over SSH and GUI login (Debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, google-cloud-platform, user-accounts

I am using a VM on Google Cloud Platform. Once created it can be accessed through SSH through the GCP web GUI. When I access through SSH, I can use `sudo` to perform privileged actions. When I access through a GUI method such as Chrome Desktop or VNC, I do not have sudo privilege. However I get my same username through `whoami` in either case.

I am confused because I have some assumptions:

- `whoami` indicates the current user by their name.
- There is only one user for a given name on the whole system, and vice versa.
- `sudo` applies to the current user (the same one as `whoami`)
- A user's authentication and sudo properties are the same across the whole system.

If these are true I don't understand how there is different `sudo` behavior when I log in different ways.

---

Update 3:

I ran `sudo usermod -aG sudo username` and after rebooting the user has sudo privileges everywhere. Nothing changed in the sudoers files. I didn't think to check the groups file before making the change.

I think everything is fine now from a practical aspect. I still don't understand how the same user can have different sudo privileges in different places.

---

Update 2:

In `/etc/sudoers` the non-commented lines (and directive) are:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

in `sudoers.d` is `google_sudoers` containing

`%google-sudoers ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

OS version: Debian 10 (buster) Linux 4.19.0-17-cloud-amd64

---

Update:

Unfortunately maybe it could be caused by some features Google have added relating to a google-sudoers group.

Relevant logs from `/var/log/auth.log`

```
gpasswd[2309]: user user_me added by root to group google-sudoers
```

Succcessful sudo:

```
sudo: user_me : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user_me ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/echo test
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by user_me(uid=0)
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Unsuccessful sudo:

```
sudo: user_me : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/user_me ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/echo test
```

I still am not sure how the behavior can be different for the same user.

Comment: Try adding your username o the sudo group: **sudo usermod -aG sudo username**. If that solves the problem compare the differences.

Comment: Need of some additional information to troubleshoot this issue :
1.Run 'tail -f /var/log/auth.log' and let each user logon to see if there are any issues and also  Run "id -a" and provide the output.
2.Can you confirm if the VM is using OSLOGIN and the image used by the VM is a google provided one?